# ViewModel trigger CollectionChanged to track ID value

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I have a situation in a new WinRT app where I need to manage an ID property on a collection of objects. Essentially I'm holding the unique ID for each object which I need to increment for each new object added. This is because I'll be serializing to XML to save the data so need to manage this ID myself. If I was using SQL it would be an auto incrementing field.

The best way I could come up with was to set this using a method called from the constructor and then have a collection changed handler help me to update the value each time.

Here is the view model class:

```
using MM.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace MM.ViewModels
{
    public class VehiclesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public VehiclesViewModel()
        {
            Vehicles = new ObservableCollection<Vehicle>();
            NewVehicle = new Vehicle();
            NextVehicleID = CalculateHighestID(Vehicles.AsQueryable()) + 1;
            Vehicles.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(VehicleCollectionChanged);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Vehicle> _vehicles;
        public ObservableCollection<Vehicle> Vehicles
        {
            get 
            { 
                return _vehicles; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (_vehicles != value)
                {
                    _vehicles = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Vehicles"));
                }
            }
        }

        void VehicleCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                NextVehicleID += 1;
            }
        }

        public Vehicle NewVehicle { get; set; }

        private int _nextVehicleID;
        public int NextVehicleID 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return _nextVehicleID; 
            }
            private set
            {
                _nextVehicleID = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NextVehicleID"));
            }
        }

        private int CalculateHighestID(IQueryable<Vehicle> vehicles)
        {
            var query = vehicles.OrderByDescending(v => v.VehicleID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (query != null)
            {
                return query.VehicleID;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and here is a text button click method I added on the xaml page to add an item.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vm.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle { VehicleID = vm.NextVehicleID });
}
```

However, the VehicleCollectionChanged is never called. As a test I used the same code to add a vehicle from the constructor method and that did work.

Can anyone explain why the method would not be called with adding a vehicle from the xaml button click?

Also, is there a better overall approach to keep track of an ID value for the next record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your ID have to be an `int` (or incremental for that matter)? Could it be a GUID? At least then you could leave the creation up to the `Vehicle` class. As for why the event isn't being called, are you ever re-assigning the "Vehicles" property on your viewmodel? Is there a reason you have a public "set" for that property? You could potentially set a new ObservableCollection to "Vehicles" and not 1) unhook from the old event and 2) hook-up the CollectionChanged event to the new collection.

Comment: I went for an int for two reasons. The first was in case I later put a webapi back end on this app which may well use an incremental int as the primary key in the database. My second reason was a probably irrational dislike for GUIDs.

Comment: I'm still learning c# so don't really follow what your suggesting. I presumed I needed pubic set as I will add to the collection from the view. I assumed by adding an item from the viewmodel the changedevent would be raised.

Comment: You will be adding to your collection from your viewmodel...your view will simply have some "visible means" of letting your viewmodel know it should add a new item (e.g. a button with a binding to a command on your viewmodel, in which the command Execute method adds a new item to your collection. The only reason you would need a "set" on the Vehicles collection is if you plan on assigning a new ObservableCollection from outside of your viewmodel (it doesn't sound like you need to). BUT, if for some reason you DO need to, you need to make sure you unhook from the collection changed event

Comment: I tried editing my comment but time ran out...I realized you're adding from the code-behind of the view. This would not really conform to the model-view-viewmodel "pattern" you're trying attempting to follow. I suggest you read up on Commanding and the rest of MVVM. What I was getting at in my initial answer about why the CollectionChanged event wasn't running was that you need to check and see if you're assigning a new ObservableCollection to your Vehicles property anywhere else in the code...this would mean that you subscribed to the event on the only collection, but added to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping a counter in your Vehicle class?

```
public class Vehicle
{
    static int NextId = 1;
    static object IdLock = new Object();

    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    ...

    public Vehicle(int nextId = 0)
    {
         // can probably use interlocked increment instead
         // of keeping a separate lock object
         lock (IdLock)
         {
             if (nextId == 0)
             {
                 VehicleId = NextId++;
             }
             else
             {
                 NextId = nextId;
                 VehicleId = nextId;
             }
         }
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead of setting NextId = 1, you may want to set it based on what is in your saved XML file. That way, it doesn't always start at 1.

Comment: I hadn't considered this as must confess I'm not sure why it's better to try this in the vehicle class rather than the main view model class. I didn't want this class to be dependent on knowing about the other items in the xml / in memory collection.

Comment: I've researched this a bit further and now understand what you're suggesting. I didn't know what a static variable was, but now I do. I have this working, but not the initial set of the ID as not sure the best way to do that. Can I pass a variable in the initial creation of the first object?

Comment: As you suggested, it is possible to pass in the ID on creation of the first object. The code above has been changed to allow this.